# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.4.4 invalid on install angular2-virtual-scroll

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, npm-install

I developing an Ionic 2.3 Web app and need to use virtual scroll.

But when I try to intall angular2-virtual-scroll library I get this error:

```
corp-now@ E:\Projetos\Ionic2\CorpNow
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.4.4 invalid
`-- angular2-virtual-scroll@0.1.5
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It seems a problem with Ionic version. Solved by using Ionic 3 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem with the Ionic 2/Angular 2 version.

Solved by using Ionic 3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add 3rd party module for the virtual scroll? It is an inbuilt feature of Ionic 2.

> Virtual Scroll displays a virtual, "infinite" list. An array of
>   records is passed to the virtual scroll containing the data to create
>   templates for. The template created for each record, referred to as a
>   cell, can consist of items, headers, and footers.
>
> For performance reasons, not every record in the list is rendered at
>   once; instead a small subset of records (enough to fill the viewport)
>   are rendered and reused as the user scrolls.

**Example:**

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="items">

  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
    {{ item }}
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

You can read more about it [**on the doc here.**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/)

Comment: Because Ionic 2's virtual scroll have some limitations. For example, I need to set virtual scroll size and position but the its virtual scroll fills the whole content area and it's not possible to change that.